# Angular Material design checkbox black foreground color (symbol color)

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am using a `<mat-checkbox> ... </mat-checkbox>` component within my application and I need to se the color of the symbol (the "tick" ✓ ) to black. I am able to set the background color via css, but nothing works for the "foreground" color.

code:

```
my.ts
          <mat-checkbox name="{{field.name}}"
                        [ngModel]="field.valueChecked"
                        ...
                        [ngClass]="{
                 'mandatory': field.mandatory == true
                 ,'optional': field.mandatory == false
                 ,'checkbox' : true}"
                 >
          </mat-checkbox>


my.css
    .checkbox {
        background-color: #3197ee !important;
        color: #050911 !important;
    }
```

Any solution how to change the color is welcome!

Comment: I guess you have to create a new  **custom theme** for your primary, secondary colors

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try with this

```
.mat-checkbox-checkmark-path {
    stroke: #000 !important;
}
```

OR

```
/deep/ .mat-checkbox-checkmark-path {
    stroke: #000 !important;
}
```

Comment: The first solution works flawlessly! I would not prefer the second, because I have read, that the 'deep' is being deprecated and may not work in all browsers.
Thanks!

Comment: Great ! Yes, `/deep/` will be deprecated soon.

Comment: Works on Angular 7 with ::ng-deep too

Comment: It works with `/deep/` but not in a *custom theme* ><

Answer (score 0):

Please try below CSS code. It will work.

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after {
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   width: 1.2ex;
   height: 0.4ex;
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
   top: 0.9ex;
   left: 0.4ex;
   border: 3px solid #000000;
   border-top: none;
   border-right: none;
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
   -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
   -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
   transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
   line-height: 2.1ex;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
    position: absolute;
    left: -999em;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label::before {
   content: "";
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: -25%;
   height: 2ex;
   width: 2ex;
   background-color: #3197ee;
   border: 1px solid rgb(166, 166, 166);
   border-radius: 4px;
   box-shadow: inset 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
   margin-right: 0.5em;
}
```

Comment: I have used similar solution with the default html checkbox (<input type="checkbox" ... >), where it worked, but had to switch to the material design checkbox, where this solution does not work for me. But thanks anyway

Comment: yes, as I said, for the <input type="checkbox" ... > it works, but not for the **<mat-checkbox ... >** checkbox